# Entity Framework POCO T4 sometimes creates an EntityCollection and sometimes creates a FixUpCollection

Tags: entity-framework-4, poco, t4

I've run into a strange issue with the Entity Framework POCOs created by the POCO T4 templates - for some objects their collection properties are created as an `EntityCollection`, and for others they're created as a `FixUpCollection`.

I'm finding this with three classes which model a product hierarchy; `ProductGroup`, `Platform` and `Product`. Each `ProductGroup` has a collection of `Platform`s, and each `Platform` has a collection of `Product`s. All the relationships are bi-directional. The collection getters and setters are exactly the same for each class because they're generated by the T4 template, so they all look (e.g.) like this:

```
public virtual ICollection<Platform> Platforms
{
    get
    {
        if (_platforms == null)
        {
            var newCollection = new FixupCollection<Platform>();
            newCollection.CollectionChanged += FixupPlatforms;
            _platforms = newCollection;
        }
        return _platforms;
    }
    set { ... }
}
```

The funny thing is, *all* the collections on `Product` and `Platform` are created as `EntityCollection`s, and *all* the collections on `ProductGroup` are created as `FixUpCollection`s. i.e. when the code first enters the getter of (e.g.) `Platform.Products`, the `_products` field is already populated with an `EntityCollection`, but when it first enters the getter shown above, `_platforms` is null and a `FixupCollection` is created and subsequently populated. Lazy-loading is working in both cases, it's just working in two different ways.

The `Entities` object has lazy-loading and proxy creation enabled. `Product`, `Platform` and `CoreProduct` objects are all dynamic EF proxies in the `Entity.DynamicProxies` namespace. I've tried eager loading the `Platform` and `ProductGroup`, which made no difference. I can't see any difference in how the classes are set up in the model viewer.

This is causing me a headache because one of the collections on `ProductGroup` contains thousands of objects, and I want to query that collection. As far as I know (please do correct me if I'm wrong) I can't query a `FixUpCollection` without loading all the objects into memory, which is not the case for an `EntityCollection` because I can use [`CreateSourceQuery()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896438.aspx). Has anyone seen this behaviour before? Is there some setting I'm missing somewhere? Any pointers or help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am curious as to what template you are using that creates this issue. I am using the POCO templates from http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/23df0450-5677-4926-96cc-173d02752313 - and they don't seem to create either of these object types. Are you using a template from a different source?

Comment: I'm pretty sure those are the ones I was using - the site notes that "the POCO generator has been updated", so maybe it was an older version... it's the ModelGenerator.tt file which contains the definition for the `FixUpCollection` class.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't query a FixUpCollection without loading all the objects into
>   memory, which is not the case for an EntityCollection.

There is no difference between `FixUpCollection` and `EntityCollection` in terms of querying. `EntityCollection` is used by dynamic proxy for lazy loading and if you try to query on the property of this type, lazy loading will still load all records and query will be executed as Linq-to-objects.

Your problem is most probably related to [violating some rule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd468057) for creating lazy loding proxy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I've updated my question to clarify what I meant by the different 'queryability' of `FixUpCollection` and `EntityCollection` (the availability of `CreateSourceQuery()`). The `Platform.Products` and `ProductGroup.Platforms` properties are created in the exact same way - by the EF from database relationships and then by the POCO T4 templates, so I can't think why they'd be different. I'll look into it some more and see what I can find...